# Issue compiling Android 6.0 using Jack Server

Tags: android, compilation, makefile, clang, android-source

I never had a problem compiling the *AOSP* version until 5.x. Now I'm trying to compile *Android 6.0*, which switched toolchain and uses [`Jack`](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html) (*Java Android Compiler Kit*) but the compilation aborts.

The error seems to be related with a problem in compiling C object files, so the `ld` linker at some point starts producing `file is empty` errors such as the following one:

```
host SharedLib: libart (out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so)
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8//x86_64-linux/bin/ld: error: out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates/check_jni.o: file is empty
```

When I check these files their size is *0 bytes*. I tried the process two times before writing this, but every time the `make` process stops with the follosing error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so] Error 1
```

Have you experienced something like this and found a solution?

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit ambiguous, were you able to build 5.x?   Your error messages don't seem like they have much of anything to do with JACK, rather they look like a mis-configured build and/or host setup.  What exactly is your build system?  It is 64-bit, right?  Did you follow all of the setup and build instructions *exactly* or was there a point where you had to "improvise"?  Are you building an unmodified configuration?  If so, for which exact lunch target?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Hi Chris, yes I was able to build 5.x. I understand that it seems not related with JACK, but the error messages start to show up only from version 6.0, and after the line that says that the JACK Server was initialized. I'm building on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64. I firstly used `repo init` with an AOSP mirror that I had, but I also tried with a freshly downloaded one. Just the normal: `repo init` (branch `android-6.0.0_r2` for version `MRA58N` which is the one I have on my Nexus 5), `repo sync`, add drivers, `source build/envsetup.sh`, `lunch aosp_hammerhead-userdebug`, `make - j8`.